# How to implement PostgresQL tsvector for full-text search using Sequelize?

Tags: postgresql, sequelize.js

I was going through this tutorial:
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-full-text-search-in-postgresql-on-ubuntu-16-04

Where it is recommended to add a `document` column as `tsvector` and applying an index to it.

```
ALTER TABLE news ADD "document" tsvector;
CREATE INDEX idx_fts_search ON news USING gin(document);
SELECT title, content FROM news WHERE document @@ to_tsquery('Travel | Cure');
```

How do I implement the `document` column with sequelize? There is no `tsvector` data type: http://docs.sequelizejs.com/variable/index.html

(Would this be a good time to try out Knex.js?)

Comment: You should be able to specify the type as a string.  You don't have to use the builtin types.  You'll just have to do a bit of work to get the values from the database.  For reference, I have used `CITEXT` as a type in Postgres and never had an issue.

Answer (score 5):

Sequelize version 6.5.0+ has support for the `TSVECTOR` datatype. But there is as of yet no documentation anywhere that I can find, so:

Declare it:

```js
sequelize.define('User', {
  myVector: { type: DataTypes.TSVECTOR },
  ...
})
```

Populate it:

```js
User.myVector = sequelize.fn('to_tsvector', 'My Content About Travel and Apparently Some Cures')
```

Use it in a query:

```js
User.findAll({
  where: { 
    myVector: { [Op.match]: sequelize.fn('to_tsquery', 'Travel | Cure') }
  }
})
```

Explore the pull request for more details: https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/pull/12955

Answer (score 2):

Try `UPDATE news` before `CREATE INDEX`:

```sql
ALTER TABLE news ADD COLUMN document tsvector;

UPDATE news SET document = to_tsvector(coalesce(title,'') || ' ' || coalesce(content,''));

CREATE INDEX idx_fts_search ON news USING gin(document);
SELECT title, content FROM news WHERE document @@ to_tsquery('Travel | Cure');
```