# Usage of TSVECTOR and to_tsquery to filter records in Sequelize

Tags: node.js, postgresql, orm, sequelize.js, tsvector

I've been trying to get full search text to work for a while now without any success. The current documentation has this example:

```
[Op.match]: Sequelize.fn('to_tsquery', 'fat & rat') // match text search for strings 'fat' and 'rat' (PG only)
```

So I've built the following query:

```
Title.findAll({
      where: {
        keywords: {
          [Op.match]: Sequelize.fn('to_tsquery', 'test')
        }
      }
    })
```

And keywords is defined as a TSVECTOR field.

```
keywords: {
      type: DataTypes.TSVECTOR,
    },
```

It seems like it's generating the query properly, but I'm not getting the expected results. This is the query that it's being generated by Sequelize:

```
Executing (default): SELECT "id" FROM "Tests" AS "Test" WHERE "Test"."keywords" @@ to_tsquery('test');
```

And I know that there are multiple records in the database that have 'test' in their vector, such as the following one:

```
{
        "id": 3,
        "keywords": "'keyword' 'this' 'test' 'is' 'a'",
    }
```

so I'm unsure as to what's going on. What would be the proper way to search for matches based on a `TSVECTOR` field?

Comment: My bad, I accidentally typed that extra coma while writing the post. I've corrected it, the original query didn't had that syntax error.

Comment: When you run that query directly in the database (like with `psql`) does it return any rows?  If you run `select $$'keyword' 'this' 'test' 'is' 'a'$$::tsvector @@ to_tsquery('test');` does it return true?  What is default_text_search_config set to?

Comment: Running the command directly in the database through psql works as expected. Your provided query also returns true, so it must be a problem with Sequelize, I believe.

Answer (score 0):

It's funny, but these days I am also working on the same thing and getting the same problem.

I think part of the solution is here ([How to implement PostgresQL tsvector for full-text search using Sequelize?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45845150/how-to-implement-postgresql-tsvector-for-full-text-search-using-sequelize)), but I haven't been able to get it to work yet.

If you find examples, I'm interested. Otherwise as soon as I find the solution that works 100% I will update this answer.

What I also notice is when I add data (seeds) from sequelize, it doesn't add the lexemes number after the data of the field in question. Do you have the same behavior ?

last thing, did you create the index ?

```
CREATE INDEX tsv_idx ON data USING gin(column);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).